# VBA RowSource com variável

Tags: vba

Como faço para colocar uma planilha variavel em uma RowSource? estou tentando concatenar com a ultima linha mas esta dando erro:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim plan As Worksheet
Dim lin As Range
Dim fim As Range

Optionapos = True

If Optionapos = True Then
    Set plan = Worksheets("CadReu")
Else
    Set plan = Worksheets("CadReuOlde")
End If

With plan

'atualiza a caixa localizar
Dim totaldelinhas As Integer
totaldelinhas = plan.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'formreunioes.cxLocalizar2.ColumnCount = .Columns.Count
formreunioes.cxLocalizar2.RowSource = .Range("A1:A" & totaldelinhas)

End With
```

Comment: Você não disse qual o código do erro que estava dando. O que pode ter acontecido é que você estava passando o valor que vinha de `plan.Range("A1:A" & totaldelinhas)` e não o valor de texto que definia o RowSource. De qualquer maneira você resolveu, sugiro mover a resposta para onde efetivamente deveria ser a resposta e depois marcar como correto. Não fica nada legível editar a pergunta colocando a resposta. Abraço.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado por sua resposta e por sua dica, eu já arrumei o local da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi alterando o código sobretudo o tipo da variável plan As Worksheet para para string e funcionou, como segue:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim plan As String
Dim lin As Range
Dim fim As Range

Optionapos = True

If Optionapos = True Then
plan = "CadReu"
Else
plan = "CadReuOlde"
End If

'atualiza a caixa localizar
Dim totaldelinhas As Long
totaldelinhas = Worksheets(plan).UsedRange.Rows.Count

formreunioes.cxLocalizar2.RowSource = plan & "!" & "A2:A" & totaldelinhas
```